# Magento - How to send an email with a custom template?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've installed a gateway module which works through a site-wide based payment, I mean, the customer pay the order inside the store. I know all payment statuses for any transaction, for example, 0 = "Order received", 1 = "Checking payment", 2 = "Authorized" and others. I would like to send an email to the customer (with Bcc to store administrator) to notice that the payment hasn't been authorized. Can I create a custom email template from admin dashboard and send an email using that new custom template? I would like also to put a link on the message which allows the customer trying make a payment again.

Any lights??

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first question: It's not possible to do in admin panel only. In admin panel you can only translate *already existing* email templates.

Answer to the second question: dig into code, for example, take a look at the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail()` method, and then come back if you have some concrete questions.

P. S. it's always a good idea to include "what have I already tried" section to your questions.

Comment: Ok. What does "Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail()" do? Can you summarize? I'm not an expert in programming, so because of that I'm here. Thanks.

Comment: You should hire a developer in this case. Magento is a complex system and stackoverflow is for answering concrete questions about concrete problems. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic